# Solving for inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$ |x - 5 | \le 2$$
$$ - 2 \le x - 5 \le 2$$
$$3 \le x \le 7$$
$$[3,7]$$

---

$$ |x-5|  > 2$$
$$x - 5 < -2 \text{ or } x - 5 > 2$$
$$ x < 3 \text{ or } x > 7$$

---

I would like to understand why are we flipping the values and sign whenever we are solving the negative values of the inequalities.

i.e., $|x-5| \le 2$ where the negative portion is $-2 \le x-5$ and for $|x-5| > 2$ it becomes $x-5 < -2$

Comment: $X>0$ implying $-x <0$ is it clear now?

Comment: Intuitively we can think like this: distance between $x$ and $5$ is greater than 2 on the number line. (Still you have to make sense of it symbolically, you may follow 5xum's answer

Comment: The "one-example reason" is that for negative numbers the stuff is $-5<-2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|a| < 2$, then you have two options:

1. If $a \geq 0$, then $|a| = a$ which means $a<2$.
2. If $a<0$, then $|a|=-a$ so the inequality becomes $-a<2$, and after multiplying the inequality by $-1$, that becomes $a> -2$.

Once you understand those two options, you merge them together and you can just say:

> $|a|<2$ is equivalent to $-2<a<2$.

which is exactly what happens in your example.

Answer (score 2):

$|x-\color{blue}5| > \color{red}2$ means $x$ is **more than** $\color{red}2$ units away from $\color{blue}5$.

In other words, the distance between $x$ and $5$ must be strictly larger than $2$ units.  There are two cases:  The case where $x$ is larger than or equal to $5$ and the case where $x$ is smaller than $5$.

If $x$ is larger than or equal to $5$, then the distance between $x$ and $5$ is $x-5$.  Thus we need $x - 5 > 2$.

If $x$ is smaller than $5$, then the distance between $x$ and $5$ is $5-x$.  Thus we need $5-x > 2$, which is the same thing as saying $x-5 < -2$.

It also helps to draw a number line:

[image]

To satisfy $|x-5| > 2$, $x$ must be **more than** $2$ units away from $5$.  This means $x$ must be **completely outside** of the red interval above (including being away from the endpoints $3$ and $7$, since those are **exactly** $2$ units away from $5$, which is not **more than** $2$ units away from $5$).

---

Another way of interpreting the above is to note the following:

$$|x-5| = \begin{cases} x-5, & x \ge 5 \\ -(x-5), & x < 5 \end{cases} $$

So in order to solve $|x-5| > 2$, we must separately consider the cases $x-5 > 2$ and $-(x-5) > 2$.  And $-(x-5) > 2$ is equivalent to $x-5 < -2$.

So overall we see that $|x-5| > 2$ means we consider $x - 5 > 2$ and $x -5 < -2$ separately.

Note that this is just a shorter way of thinking about exactly what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

The way you should think about this is: $|x+5|<2$ tells us that the absolute value of whatever is between the bars is less than two, so what can the number between the bars (in the example $x+5$) be?

It must surely be less than two as $|2|=2$ is the "boundary" value. Let's consider numbers that are less than two (in a continuous way, but pick some representatives, e.g. $1$, $0.5$, $0$ and so on).

$|1|<2$, $|0|<2$, however, don't stop here, check what happens if you enter negative numbers.

$|-1|=1<2$, $|-1,5|=1,5<2$, $|-2|=2$ is the "boundary" value, as if we go further into negative numbers (backwards on a number line), e.g. $|-2.1|$, $|-2.2|$, $|-3|$, $|-15|$, $|-100|$ and so on are all greater than $2$. Recall that the numbers you inserted between the absolute value bars were of the form $x+5$, we obtained that they must be $<2$ and at the same time $>-2$, hence $x+5<2$ AND $x+5>-2$ (to find the set of the solutions, solve both inequalities and take the intersection, as the conjunction is AND).

Answer (score 0):

By multiplying with $-1$ in $a>b$, we get:

$$(-a)<(-b)$$

Because you also change the $>$ sign because of the minus.

---

Think of it like this:

- You have two positive numbers, $a$ and $b$, with $a>b$. You can put them on an axis, like so:$$------------\:\overline{\underline{\text{Origin}}}\:------\:b ---\:a-$$
- The axis shows that the $d(a,\text{Origin})>d(b,\text{Origin})$ and $a,b>0$, and thus $a>b$.
- Multiply the two numbers by $-1$ and place them on the axis again:$$-(-a)---(-b)------\:\overline{\underline{\text{Origin}}}\:------------$$
- The axis shows that $-d(a,\text{Origin})<-d(b,\text{Origin})$, so $(-a)<(-b)$.

The above graphically shows that $$a>b\implies (-a)<(-b),\:\:\forall \:a,b\in\mathbb{R}$$

---

An example would be easier to understand, perhaps:
$$\color{blue}{5>3}, \text{ multiply by }\color{red}{-1}\implies \color{red}{-5<-3}\text{ (True)}$$